# While I'm running my c code, there is an another line after my desired output which I do not want

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code

The line after my output is :

> [1] + Done                       "/usr/bin/gdb" --interpreter=mi --tty=${DbgTerm} 0<"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-In-llrvtjyg.htu" 1>"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-qvd0kncp.rkk"

are there any ways to remove this without affecting the way my code works and other stuff works?

Im on linux mint btw and use vs code as the IDE.

I asked chatGPT about it but it seems too complicated since I do not have any idea what im doing as its told by the ai.
Pls help.

Comment: Never ask ChatGPT a technical question whose answer you do not already know.  It is very good at writing answers that *sound* good, but its likelihood of answering *correctly* plummets with increasing technical detail.  Incorrect answers that nevertheless sound good are your worst-case scenario when you're looking for help.

Comment: Anyway, the line you quoted is not written by your program.  Rather, it is an artifact of the way your IDE is running the program.  It may or may not be possible to configure VSC such that that line is no longer printed, but if I were you, I would just ignore it.

Comment: Nobody can answer until you show what you *did input* to get that output. Also it does not seem to be a C programming question.

Comment: @U.Windl any input would result in the same, like:
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
 printf("Hello, World\n");
printf("hello\nhi");
return 0;
}

and the output would be:

Hello, World
hello
hi[1] + Done                       "/usr/bin/gdb" --interpreter=mi --tty=${DbgTerm} 0<"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-In-iz4urnby.xxg" 1>"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-3lpjjeyc.wld

Comment: Please *don't* add "unformatted" code in a comment when being asked to improve your question: Use **Edit** to edit your question instead. Despite of that "any" input will surely not cause that effect.

Answer (score 0):

According to details you give, I think this is coming from the bash's job.
Try this:

```bash
disown $!
```

Comment: The message is definitely coming from the shell, but it's unclear how the OP would configure VSC to disown the job, or whether doing so would cause some other problem.

Comment: GIven that this appears to be a C program (from your tags), after you compile the source code, what happens if you run the executable from the command prompt and not from inside VS Code?

Comment: @thurizas then its completely fine, theres no problems. So, this is a VS Code problem?

Comment: @StackOverflower given that the compiled program runs fine, I would suspect that it is an issue with either the IDE or how the IDE interacts with the debugger.  I do not use VS Code so I have no other suggestions.